# How to connect to a webserver on ec2 'privately'

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip-address, vpn

I have a little web application deployed on an ec2 instance and I'd like to test it without making it publicly available.

Using an elastic IP does not solve my issue because the IP would then expose it to the outside world and we are not ready for this yet.

I'm aware of Amazon VPC but it seems a bit overkill since I don't need all those functionalities and I don't want to deal with the set up. All I need is to be able to hit the webserver by using a private IP or something like that.

Is there a quick and dirty solution for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could setup your web server to listen only on 127.0.0.1 (rather than 0.0.0.0) and then use SSH to tunnel a connection from your local machine to the instance.

From your desktop, setup the SSH connection:

```
$ ssh -L 3000:localhost:80 ec2-user@ec2-instance.amazonaws.com
```

Then visit `http://localhost:3000` in your browser and it will forward port 3000 on your desktop to port 80 on the instance, via the SSH connection.

Comment: I ended up using Putty port forwarding since I was on Windows, great!

Comment: @MarsellusWallace how did you do that? I am struggling in finding a clear implementation using Putty on Windows

Comment: @Greg Kempe how did you pass the ppk?

Comment: Or in ~/.ssh/config: `Host <host> HostName <host-name> User <host-user> IdentityFile <host-user-priv-key> LocalForward 127.0.0.1:3000 127.0.0.1:80`

Answer (score 1):

Create a security group that only allows traffic from your IP (the IP of the machine running the browser where you will do the testing) to the web server port (80, probably) and assign this security group to your ec2 instance.

This way only you can access the web app.

If you need to work from different locations, write a simple script to update the security group and add your current IP. These changes are applied immediately and do not require a restart. You can grab your current IP from [whatismyip](http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/) and use the [Amazon SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress.html) to update the security group.

Comment: That might be a solution in certain cases. Imagine that I have to run a demo from some other location and I don't have time to change the security rules though. Is there a way to guarantee access only to people that have a certain private key or something like that?

Comment: Update my answer to address multiple locations. private keys are relevant in ssh-related solutions. You can also use client-side certificates, but these require changes to your web app. Security group operate at the 'network' level and are therefore transparent to your app.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an EIP to access your instance - it has a public DNS name associated with it automatically.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to restrict access to a given instance (whether addressed by EIP or with the public DNS name) only to people that have a given private key or something like that?

Comment: If your instance is a Linux machine, for example, and you only allow ssh connections, then only you (who have the private key) could log into the machine.

Comment: it is linux and i'm able to ssh in it. What I'm trying to restrict is the access to my web application. Ideally I could create a vpn and use private IPs but I was hoping on an easier way

Comment: turn on https and use basic authentication in your web server

Answer (score 0):

If you want an EC2 instance that is truly *private*, you need to look at launching it inside of a VPC. You'll want a Bastion Host in your public subnet and your instance in the private subnet.