# Restricting access to Web Service on Amazon EC2

Tags: java, web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I have created an app and deployed on Tomcat Running in Linux EC2 Instance. That app is simply a Hello World! app. I want to restrict this app and let only authenticated users to access this service. As Public DNS or IP is available anyone can directly call the service from browser. Please tell me how can I secure the call from URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding authentication to your web app requires you to write some authentication code into your application. Amazon can't add authentication to your web service.

What AWS can do is limit the IP addresses that can reach your web server by using security groups. So you can have your instance use a security group that only allows access from your IP.

There is a very similar question here:
[How to connect to a webserver on ec2 'privately'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450762/how-to-connect-to-a-webserver-on-ec2-privately)